# UK Working Visa

Tags: visas, working-visas

We have a talent coming into UK in Q4 to perform.

They are from the Middle East.

We are not registered as a visa sponsor - must we be?

EDIT:
Music performer, 2/3 DAY stay.

Comment: What kind of talent, what kind of performance, and, importantly for this site, for how long? Questions about extended professional stays belong on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Music Performer, 2/3 day stay. @phoog

Comment: @JohnC please add the extra explanations as an edit to the question

Comment: @Newton I did. It appears it has been edited out by someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to be registered to invite a performer to visit on a Permitted Paid Engagement Visa https://www.gov.uk/permitted-paid-engagement-visa